# Manipulating programmatically-created UIViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

What is the best way to manipulate properties such as `hidden` and `alpha` etc for a view you create programmatically?

For example, suppose you do this:

```
  [self insertSubview:self.newview aboveSubview:self.tempSplash];
```

Anything you do to `newview` at this point has no effect on the actual view onscreen, I've noticed.

Now I could get a pointer to my new subview, but if it is not in the nib, then the only option I can think of doing something clunky like:

```
 UIView*controlPointer=[self.subviews objectAtIndex:whatever];
```

The problem is, there is no elegant way to figure out the index number of the newly created view and handling index numbers of subviews just seems a bit extreme. Is there another good way to get a pointer to this programmatically created subview, so I can do things like:

```
 controlPointer.alpha=1;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have self.newView, you should just be able to do

```
  self.newView.alpha=1;
```

or

```
 self.newView.hidden=NO;
```

If you're not seeing a response to this, something else is wrong.
Are you sure that self.newView is not null?

```
 NSLog(@" self.newview is 0x%x", self.newView);  // should NOT be 0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are adding `self.newview` suggests that you have an ivar of type UIView? So any time you need to change a property of the view just call something like :

```
self.newview.hidden = YES
```